# How use Twitter bootstrap script separately on my project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I use **Twitter Bootstrap scripts** ( like scrollspy ,affix ... ) in my project without include all bootstarp CSS and JS. I have try to use scrollspy.js but in all samples they include complete bootstrap.css and that change my template, and event not work script! ( always select last navbar element. )
Is there any clear solution?

Answer (score 1):

Twitter Bootstrap is very pretty tight coupled with css when it comes to animations, transitions and other effects. But JS files alone should work for the most cases, because they target classes or data-attributes. Simply include JS files without CSS files and add classes that are needed to work with your project, you should get desired functionality without bootstrap styling.

Answer (score 1):

You need to at least include `jquery.js` to make the Bootstrap plugins work. You can also include only certain parts of the bootstrap CSS. Downloading the git will give you dozens of separate `.less` files. In your case, you could then simply grab `variables.less` and `scrollspy.less` and create your CSS file with only those parts you actually need.